# Add kerning correction before capital V

Tags: kerning

Kerning correction works if the capital letter is in front of the small letter. The other way round spaces seems uneven.

Take for example the space between the `e` and `V` in the word `PeVatron`. It seems to be bigger than the space between `V` and `a`. How to automatically make both spaces the same width? (without manually inserting `\kern`, `\hskip` etc.)

The happens also within units, like `kV` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

PeVatron

\si{\kilo\volt}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tex has no control of inter-letter kerns they are specified by the font designer in the font metrics so depend totally on the font in use. Knuth was probably not thinking of camel cased words when tuning the kerning for computer modern

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good to know. Can you write an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX has no control of inter-letter kerns, they are specified by the font designer in the font metrics so depend totally on the font in use. As lowercase-uppercase doesn't occur in normal text, it is quite likely that such combinations were not even considered when tuning the kerning of some fonts.

You could in theory make a virtual font which used the same underlying font but with additional kerns specified but that is quite a lot of work. There are also other possibilities if you use lualatex or (in a more restricted way) xelatex).